# Who is the issuer of this Personal certificate

Tags: security, certificate, x509

In the certificate store of my Windows 10 PC (not joined to a domain) there is a certificate under Personal as follows:

```
subject=/CN=0c4e397b-ea9d-48a5-9cfc-0366effbd081
issuer=/DC=net/DC=windows/CN=MS-Organization-Access/OU=82dbaca4-3e81-46ca-9c73-0950c1eaca97
```

This certificate is used when a web site I visit requests for client certificates.

Who is the issuer? Is it a global CA or is it something local to my machine? I can't seem to find it in the certificate store on my PC. Where can I find more information about this issuer?

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is used for associating the unique Windows device against a device object record stored within the Azure Active Directory.

The certificate has been generated by the Azure Device Registration Service based on a certificate signing request generated on the device during the Azure AD Join process.

The [Azure Active Directory documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/overview) contains general overview about the topic and this [TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52818.azure-ad-join-behind-the-scene.aspx) describes the Azure AD Join process in detail.