# How to select the client certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, tls

I am using Chrome and Edge to visit a web site that requires client certificate (mTLS). For the first time, both Chrome and Edge pops up a panel that asks me to select a certificate. There was only one to choose, the sole one in my Personal store (Windows 10). I could visit the web site.

After I rebooted my computer, when I tried to do the same, I received a 400 error response with the message "No required SSL certificate was sent". How do I include the certificate in the request again?

Answer (score 2):

Restart Chrome, so that the certificate popup is shown again.

To do that, type in the following address into chrome:

```
chrome://restart
```

This closes and reopens the windows with all the tabs you had (as it worked for me, no warranty)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If the certificate has disappeared from the Personal store,
it should still exist somewhere on your computer from when you received it.

Try to import again the certificate to the Personal store:

- Open Chrome
- Click the three-points menu at the top right corner
- Select *Settings > Privacy and security > Manage certificates*
- In the Certificates dialog, click Import...
- Click Next, browse to the certificate file
- Continue as indicated to import the certificate.

Comment: This seems to open the Certificates MMC snap-in. My certificate is there in the Personal store, and its intended purpose is indicated as `Client Authentication`. But somehow it is not selected. There is another certificate there also for Client Authentication. Is there a way to launch that pop-up panel that I experienced the first time?

Comment: Have you installed the CA certificate in the corresponding CA stores (In other words, where did you get the certificate from)? Could you post screenshots with your certificate details?

Comment: Yes, my certificate is the one in this question:https://superuser.com/questions/1577379/who-is-the-issuer-of-this-personal-certificate

Comment: Not enough details, which is probably why you didn't get there an answer.